# Passing Multiple Strings in Concatenation Attempt to an ostringstream Parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, stream

I am trying to create a method that will accept a stream (i.e. ostringstream) parameter that will be logged to a file.

In the header file, it is declared as:

```
static void Log(const std::ostringstream& message, LoggingSeverity severity = LoggingSeverity::info);
```

However, when I try to call the method from another class, such as:

```
SimpleLogger::Log("Name registered.", SimpleLogger::LoggingSeverity::trace);
```

I am getting the following error: `E0415    no suitable constructor exists to convert from "const char []" to "std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>"`

And if I try to structure a call by concatenating strings (`input` is of type std::string), like this:

```
SimpleLogger::Log("String to int conversion of [" << input << "] failed.", SimpleLogger::LoggingSeverity::warning);
```

I receive the following error: `E0349   no operator "<<" matches these operands`

From the errors, I understand that the std::ostringstream parameter doesn't like the strings, but I was under the impression that the data type would provide me the needed functionality of being able to provide objects to the stream, including, for example, `int` values. Is there a better data type to achieve the desired result? Or, is the structured calls to the method incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem here is you are passing a string to a stringstram constructor, the idea is ok but the constructor is defined explicit so there is no automatic conversion to from string to stringstream, `explicit stringstream (const string& str , ios_base::openmode which = ios_base::in | ios_base::out);` , you can find details [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/stringstream/)

As for your question here is a sample code,

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void Logg(const std::ostringstream& message) {
    std::cout<<message.str()<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::string a= "other message";
    Logg(std::ostringstream("some message"));
    Logg(std::ostringstream(a));
    Logg(static_cast<std::ostringstream>(a));
}
```

Output

```
some message
other message
other message
```